# Formula to Calculate 10 Business Days from Created Date?

Tags: formula, date

How would I edit this formula to reflect a date of 10 days days after created date? It currently covers 48 hours or 2 business days.

```
CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
  0, CreatedDate + 1 + 2, /* Sun: CreatedDate + 1 wknd day + 2 days */
  4, CreatedDate + 2 + 2, /* Thurs: CreatedDate + 2 wknd days + 2 days */
  5, CreatedDate + 2 + 2, /* Fri: CreatedDate + 2 wknd days + 2 days */
  6, CreatedDate + 2 + 2, /* Sat: CreatedDate + 2 wknd days + 2 days */
  CreatedDate + 2 /* Default (Mon/Tue/Wed): CreatedDate + 2 days */
)
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since 10 business days are always 14 days (10 business days always include 2 weekends = 4 days), you can greatly simplify by using the following formula:

```
CreatedDate + 14
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas!! occam's razor: The simplest explanation is usually the correct one...

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula:

`CreatedDate +
/* 10 - number of Business days to add. Adjust in 2 lines below */
 + MOD(10,5)
 + FLOOR( 10 / 5) * 7
 + CASE(
  MOD( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
  0, 1, /* Sun: next Business day in 1 day */
  6, 2, /* Sat: next Business day in 2 days */
  0 /* is a Business day */
)`